# Can it be a harm to google indexing or ranking on random posts?

Tags: google-search-console

Will there be any harm to google indexing or google ranking on showing random posts/ad-listings on front page of website? 5-6 posts on front page will change every time a user refreshes his page.

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to do this. It does not make sense to me. It does not benefit users or search. I would not recommend this.

Comment: I have put this random function to show featured ads randomly so that each one of them gets priority accordingly.

Comment: My worry would be that search engines would think you are cloaking. Keep in mind that Google checks sites from external networks for cloaking. If each access is different, that could be an issue.

Comment: Sites that do this tend to be annoying to users and engage them less, resulting in fewer visits/clicks. I would select perhaps two to display at a time and fill the site with more content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, ideally ads should have no effect (good or ill) on rankings (which should be a measure of the site content only).

Ultimately, though, you need to avoid ads that may affect your search engine rankings. Otherwise, ads are fine. [This article](https://varvy.com/paidlinks.html) is reasonably current and covers the basics, including an extended section on general ad types and considerations for ranking considerations. As it states

> "Any advertisement that passes pagerank is against the Google guidelines."

Furthermore

> A paid link or advertisement must have a "nofollow" or must be redirected through a file that is excluded by your robots.txt file. If you know what those are, you can use the [varvy.com nofollow](https://varvy.com/tools/linkcount/) tool to check your pages.

Here is a link to the current [Google Webmaster Guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769):

> Make reasonable efforts to ensure that advertisements do not affect search engine rankings. For example, Google's AdSense ads and DoubleClick links are blocked from being crawled by a robots.txt file.

Comment: Thanks alot. By featured ads I mean posts that users will be posting on my website (similar to olx or kijiji), not Adsense or any 3rd party paid links.

Comment: I would still be somewhat careful with ad text perhaps, but I did note kijiji comes up second for "classified ads canada" in Google, so they are doing something right. Personally, I still might opt for an olx or craiglist style front page, but if you can follow kijiji's formula, it seems unlikely you will have trouble.